# Sample maximum possible data points from distribution to new distribution

Tags: python, pandas

**Context**

Assume there is a distribution of three nominal classes over each calendar week from an elicitation, e.g. like this:

```
| Week | Class | Count | Distribution | Desired Distribution |
|------|-------|-------|--------------|----------------------|
| 01   | A     | 954   |     0.36     |         0.55         |
| 01   | B     | 554   |     0.21     |         0.29         |
| 01   | C     | 1145  |     0.43     |         0.16         |
| 02   | A     | 454   |     0.21     |         0.55         |
| 02   | B     | 944   |     0.44     |         0.29         |
| 02   | C     | 748   |     0.35     |         0.16         |
```

However, the distribution does not match the distribution of the ground truth (*Desired Distribution*).
As the example shows the distribution differs quite strongly from the desired one.

**Problem**

If there were enough data points ensured for each week to just multiply the desired distribution with the sum of the count for each week (`sum(count_per_week) * desired_distribution`) the solution would be easy.
Anyhow, e.g. `Class="A"` has the highest distribution but not always the highest `Count`.

Thus, it has to be iterated over over each week in a descending fashion on the desired distribution (`desc(desired_distribution)`) and the total count for each week (`sum(count_per_week)`) has to be adjusted. This means: If the `Class` of the current iteration does not yield enough data to ensure the desired distribution of all `Class`es, the `sum(count_per_week)` has to be adjusted by this (meaning the divergence has to be substracted). Following this, the preceding calculation(s) has also to be adjusted regarding the outcome of the current iteration.

While I know the logic to to solve the problem, I struggle to do it in a `pandas-DataFrame`. I tried to iterate over the grouped DataFrame, whereby each group consists of a single week with the three classes. I also tried to implement a left-recursive function on each group.

Anyhow, I think I might be thinking too complex here and maybe there is an out-of-the-box solution I don't know about (this can a `pandas`- or `numpy`-function or just some mathematical equation which just returns the ajdusted percentage to achieve the desired distribution etc.).

**Question**

*How can I resample class-counts in a `pandas-DataFrame` to a desired other distribution?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try calculate the maximal total count for each week, then multiply that with the desired distribution. The idea is

1. Devide the `Count` by `Desired Distribution` to get the possible total
2. Calculate the minimal possible total for each week with `groupby`
3. Then multiply the possible totals with the `Desired Distribution` to get the sample numbers.

In code:

```
df['new_count'] = (df['Count'].div(df['Desired Distribution'])
    .groupby(df['Week']).transform('min')
    .mul(df['Desired Distribution'])
    //1
).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   Week Class  Count  Distribution  Desired Distribution  new_count
0     1     A    954          0.36                  0.55        954
1     1     B    554          0.21                  0.29        503
2     1     C   1145          0.43                  0.16        277
3     2     A    454          0.21                  0.55        454
4     2     B    944          0.44                  0.29        239
5     2     C    748          0.35                  0.16        132
```

Comment: Wow - that shows that I was thinking way too complex (and I'm impressed how fast you solved this Problem 0.0). The solution works and I will accept it as soon as possible :)