# Resample distribution to new distribution with maximum possible data records

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, impala

**Context**

Recently, I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67473006/sample-maximum-possible-data-points-from-distribution-to-new-distribution) how to resample a dataset with some random distribution to a particular distribution over some classes which should retrieve the maximum possible datapoints for each class.

The problem was solved - Anyhow, only in a *Python*-implementation. For my use case I now require to do it in pure SQL or rather SQL that is compatible with `Impala` or `HiveQL`.

To better understand the problem at hand, this is a fictive example of the data (how looks and how it should look like). It is a distribution of three classes per calendar week:

```
| Week | Class | Count | Distribution | Desired Distribution |
|------|-------|-------|--------------|----------------------|
| 01   | A     | 954   |     0.36     |         0.55         |
| 01   | B     | 554   |     0.21     |         0.29         |
| 01   | C     | 1145  |     0.43     |         0.16         |
| 02   | A     | 454   |     0.21     |         0.55         |
| 02   | B     | 944   |     0.44     |         0.29         |
| 02   | C     | 748   |     0.35     |         0.16         |
```

As can be seen, the distribution is random and does not match the ground truth (*Desired Distribution*). Moreover, the desired distribution differs quite strongly from the status quo.

**Problem**

It is required to get the maximum possible data records per class and calendar week. Thus, it is not possible to only multiply the *desired distribution* with the *sum of the count for each week* (`sum(count_per_week) * desired_distribution`). More challenging, the class with the highest desired data points has sometimes the fewest in the actual data (`Class="A"`") which is why this precondition is crucial.
Ultimately, the numbers have to be used to restrict the data-records to the required amount.

Therefore, it is required to find a solution grouping each calendar week, calculating the maximum possible datapoints and select the data records accordingly while doing this in SQL.

**Question**

*How can I resample a distribution of class-counts per calendar week to a desired other distribution in SQL while maintaing as much data as possible per class?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Quang Hoang's perfect answer for Python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67473006/sample-maximum-possible-data-points-from-distribution-to-new-distribution) I was able to solve this one. First take a look at the necessary calculation (namings are taken from the question):

```
new_count  = minimum( (Count / Desired_Distribution) per week ) * Desired_Distribution
```

Note that this requires calculations per week making it necessary to work with joins. Thus, I will split the query for better understanding the steps.

---

***Step 1:** Provide the basis data which represent the desired result*

```sql
with step_1 as (
    SELECT 
        , week  -- Looks e.g. like '202105' -> 5th calendar week in 2021
        , class
        , case 
            when class = "A" THEN 0.55
            when class = "B" THEN 0.29
            when class = "C" THEN 0.16
        end as Desired_Distribution
    FROM source_table
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
)
```

---

***Step 2:** Provide the minimum possible data points per class and week*

```sql
,  step_2 as (
    SELECT 
        week
        , min(Diverging_Distribution) as Minimal_Population
    FROM (
        SELECT
            week
            , class
            , case 
                when class = "A" THEN count(*) / 0.55
                when class = "B" THEN count(*) / 0.29
                when class = "C" THEN count(*) / 0.16
            end as Diverging_Distribution
        FROM source_table
    ) status_quo
    GROUP BY 1
)
```

---

***Step 3:** Provide the reference for the maximal data records possible per class*

```sql
, step_3 as (
    SELECT
        step_1.week
        , step_1.class
        , ceil(step_1.Current_Distribution * step_2.Minimal_Population) as New_Distribution
    FROM step_1
    LEFT JOIN step_2 using(week) -- Provide maximum per week, not per week and class!
)
```

---

***Result:** Put it all together -> Restrict number of data-records per class*

```sql
SELECT 
    sample.week
    , sample.class
    , sample.data_record_id
FROM (
    SELECT
        data_record_id
        , week
        , class
        , row_number() over (
            partition by 
                week
                , class
            order by data_record_id
        ) as rnk -- This provides a unique number per record and week/class
    FROM source_table
) sample
INNER JOIN step_3 on sample.week = step_3.week
        and sample.class = step_3.class
WHERE sample.rnk <= step_3.New_Distribution -- This selects the quantity of records to match the new distribution
```